# What is the right way to pass a date as a string in a specific format and return a date object with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have been looking at the momentjs [momenjs](https://momentjs.com/) documentation because I want to use it to return a date object from a date that is a string in a particular format. My code looks like this.

```
const date = moment(stringDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
console.log(date);
```

But it creates an invalid date as can be seen here.

[image: produces invalid date]

What am I doing wrong. How can I get a date object from a date string that is in a particular format?

Comment: what is `stringDate`?

Comment: What I mean is a string that is the representation of a date.

Comment: It should be `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'`. `M` represents months and `m` represents minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to parse a string then return a different format you can:

```
> moment(dateString).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Further examples: 
Official docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/
Other sources: https://coderwall.com/p/vc3msa/a-very-short-introduction-to-moment-js

Comment: But I have date that is represented as a string and I want to create a date object from that string representation of a date. It is formated in a way that I cant just pass it into a Date(datestring).

Comment: @Dan moment is smart, just pass the date string you have there, and afterwards after the moment object is created you can output  it in the desired format.
moment(stringDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')

Comment: The OP is quite correct to pass a format along with `dateString`. Not doing so is deprecated (unless you're passing in JS's ISO-8601-derived format).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder isn't this the iso format? I think it is... Also as I see it he is consistent with a standard formatting. Moment might very well identify the correct time. Read the docs for validate method

Comment: @BogdanM.: Their specific example is, yes, but their format string is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `MM:SS` for minutes:seconds, but it should be `mm:ss`; [details here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Example:

```js
const stringDate = "2018-05-11 14:25:37";
// Parsing
const m = moment(stringDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// Show it in a different format to demonstrate parsing worked
console.log(m.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"));
// Accessing the underlying Date object
const dt = m.toDate();
// Log that dateobject
console.log(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```